# EditText on focus scroll up without resize other views

Tags: android, xml, android-edittext, scrollview, adjustpan

I'm trying to get an EditText field to scroll over my cameraPreview when selected. However it is now resizing the cameraPreview. I would be content with a adjustPan behaviour however I want the actionBar to stay on screen. I suspect it could be done with a scrollView however uptill no I can't prevent the cameraPreview from resizing.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/cameraPreview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

    </FrameLayout>

<!-- Fix for black overlay on menu -->
<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >
</FrameLayout>
<ScrollView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        >
      <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputCode"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/White"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@color/Green"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    </EditText>
 </ScrollView>
```

[image: deformed apple]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally decided to scroll the whole view including the action bar

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for the solution for a long time ,finally I got it;

It's simple,

First, use scroll_view as your View which has a edit_text child;

Second, use a Relative_Layout(Linear_Layout is useless) as the child of your Scroll_View

Then,you can see it works
notes: (1)Do not use layout_align_Parent_Bottom ,user layout_below instead 
       (2)You have no need to  specify window_Soft_Input_Model,the default is OK;

here is the example

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rootlinearlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
            android:text="Button1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button6" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button4" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView1"
            android:ems="10" >
        </EditText>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button8" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button9" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button10" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button5" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/captionbottomrelativelayout"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="Button" />`enter code here`
</LinearLayout>
```

`enter code here

Answer (score 0):

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan"
```

add the above line in your manifest activity.